Intermittent random spikes in CPU load on Ubuntu system
Running Ubuntu 22.04 and have more recently noticed (~1 month) random spikes in CPU load that have caused overall system sluggishness (eg, spike from ~1.3 to 4/5/6/7+, growing steadily without intervention).
Having some basic monitoring set up, I'm able to see which processes are using extra resources via htop in a terminal and have, at different times seen applications like Thunderbird (email client), Firefox and Brave seemingly 'trigger' the spike, often times (frankly inexplicably) 'infecting' Plex Media Server (inexplicably, because nothing I'm doing involves Plex).
Remedy here is typically to kill the problem process, after which balance is restored but what other tools might I use to identify the underlying issue (aside from sorting process on CPU usage in htop)?  And generally, any thoughts about what the cause might be?
At the time of spikes, I'm not typically doing anything intensive (most recently have been working in a Firefox window, another time editing a file within Spyder IDE, etc).  Would make sense, for instance, if I was working with dozens of tabs in FF and my cache had just blown up, but most recently this happened while returning to my FF home screen via shortcut with ~10 tabs open).
Any thoughts are much appreciated.
